# How to quickly test the composite input of a monitor

Tags: display, external-display, composite-video

What off the shelf product can I use to the quickly test a monitor through its composite input that is cheap and portable (battery operated).

I have several vintage computer equipment which uses composite output and I would like to shop used electronics for a monitor. But I want to make sure that the monitor works and is receiving output.

I have no "known working" devices and I don't want to base a purchase on the output any of this equipment due to its age.

I'm thinking that maybe a portable DVD player would work but I would ideally like something that has no moving parts so that it is less likely to break. This is for testing purposes only so the actual device used for testing isn't important but I do want something portable.

This would be for testing NTSC signals.

Comment: It is simply rare to find a composite video output on a device these days because it is both analog and standard definition.  You neglect to mention which composite video standard you need, i.e. PAL or NTSC.  If you're in the USA and the over-the-air TV reception is good, an ATSC converter box would be a suitable source device.  For portable you would have to find an old portable VCR or camcorder.   Back in the days of analog video, portable video equipment was not common.

Comment: Your question is not really on topic here, try asking at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/three-ways-to-display-your-raspberry-pi-on-a-monitor-or-tv/ -> @ Display Output Using RCA